Google Script Shows Completed Execution When Run but No Results are Generated
The script creates a google calendar event upon form submission. It has run without a problem for 4 years and now doesn't work when the form is submitted or when run from the editor. Below is what happens when run from the editor. There are several logger events that would be seen as output. The runtime is 1 sec. Prior to this the script would produce the following error message: an unknown error has occurred, please try again later when run from the editor. That corrected itself.
Editor Run:



Execution log






11:31:47 AM
Notice
Execution started


11:31:48 AM
Notice
Execution completed



When run upon form submission the following error is produced in the executions log:
Exception: Event start time must be before event end time.
    at [unknown function](Client Reminder to Google Calendar:31:48)
    at create Client Reminder(Client Reminder to Google Calendar:11:8)

This would seem suggest that the event date isn't in the future, but it is for the failed attempts.
2024-11-03
2024-11-01
2024-11-17
2024-11-28
2024-11-03
2024-11-03
2024-11-03
2024-11-03

The last successful execution was Oct 18th. Each run since has been in error. No problem prior to 10/18 over hundreds of executions.











Head
createClientReminder
Trigger
Oct 22, 2024, 2:02:48 PM
Failed


Head
createClientReminder
Trigger
Oct 22, 2024, 11:12:20 AM
Failed


Head
createClientReminder
Trigger
Oct 21, 2024, 2:05:32 PM


Head
createClientReminder
Trigger
Oct 18, 2024, 5:18:49 PM
Completed



function createClientReminder() {

  var reminderCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("elbqdu5q0q6anegmd8k9pl0kms@group.calendar.google.com"); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function(entry,index,array) {
    var draftDate = entry[4];
    var firstName = entry[5];
    var lastName = entry[6];
    var phoneNumber = entry[7];
    var product = entry[8];
    var faceAmount = entry[10];
    var premium = entry[11];
    var agentfirstName = entry[1];
    var agentlastName = entry[2];
    var agentphone = entry[21];
    var clientEmail = entry[23];
    var policyStatus = entry[12];
    var website = 'familylifeinsurancegroup.com'
    var reminderStatus = entry[20];
    var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    var agentfullName = agentfirstName + " " + agentlastName;
    

      if(reminderStatus == 'Add Reminder' && policyStatus !== 'Declined'){
            var eventSeries = reminderCalendar.createEventSeries(fullName,
      new Date(draftDate),
      new Date(draftDate + 1),
      CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addMonthlyRule().times(12),
      {description: clientEmail + '\n' + phoneNumber + '\n' + '[Client=' + firstName + ']' + '\n' + '[Premium=$' + premium + ']' + '\n' + '[Carrier=' + product + ']' + '\n' + '[Agent=' + agentfullName + ']' + '\n' + '[AgentPhone=' + agentphone + ']'+ '\n' + '[AgentPage=' + website + ']'});
      
      //let description = eventSeries.getId
      //let event = calendar.getEventById(eventId);

      let timeStamp = new Date();
      sheet.getRange(index + 1,21).setValue(timeStamp);
      
  Logger.log('Event Series ID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
  Logger.log(fullName);
  Logger.log(draftDate);
  Logger.log(draftDate + 1);
  Logger.log(phoneNumber);
  Logger.log(product);
  Logger.log(faceAmount)
  Logger.log(reminderStatus);
  Logger.log("The value at index " + index + " is " + entry + ".");
  
      }
    
  
  });
        
    

    }

Based on other post I added the script ID to the library, closed and reopened the sheet, cleared browsing data, and changed the date format from "Plain Text" to mm/dd/yyyy.

The Code is working well and as I copied  and replicated given on the script sample.

@LimeHusky Ditto

1) Would you please provide details of the trigger. 2) var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); can be a problem in a triggered function. Is there is a reason why you didn't use, say, getSheetByName()? 3) The script responds to a Google Form, is there a reason why it uses sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); rather than Event Objects?
